# Sample in Visual studio 2010 doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to use this code from VS help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx

But it doesn't work! I do exactly as written, but when I right click nothing happens.
I can't understand why... please help!

Comment: Are you getting any compiler errors, or errors in general?

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting the context menu portion to work, you have to call `InitializeContextMenu` in the form's constructor or Load event handler. The documentation for the sample on that page doesn't mention this (it only mentions `InitializeDataGridView`)

(Mind you, the documentation for the sample doesn't seem to mention the context menu parts of the sample at all, so far as I can see)

Comment: Thanks for answering. no questions anymore)

Answer (score 1):

The sample code is missing a calls to both the `InitializeDataGridView()` and `InitializeContextMenu()` routine that essentially sets up for the Data Grid View and the context menu that allows the right-click for searching.

The article does mention adding your own call to the `InitializeDataGridView()` routine, but misses mentioning the `InitializeContextMenu()` routine.

To correct this, double-click on a blank area of the form to create a `Form1_Load` procedure (which will automagically wire-up the Form's Load event for you), then add in a call to `InitializeDataGridView()` and `InitializeContextMenu()`

Your code-behind should end up with the following code added in addition to the MSDN sample code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     InitializeDataGridView()
     InitializeContextMenu()
End Sub
```